# How to update a Solr document field which contains a hyphen using PHP solr client

Tags: php, solr

The Solr document field is like car-id, I try to use following code to update the record but failed.

```
$document->car = $car; 
$document->car-id = $carid;   <----  

$solr->addDocument($document);
$solr->commit();
```

How do I update this record?

ps. all other field can be updated, just that car-id can't.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: [Thu Jul 24 10:42:12.466048 2014] [:error] [pid 13611] [client ] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in update.php on line 133. line 133 is $document->car-id = $carid;